# How to create proper relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two types of users: Personal and Business. Personal user can belong to Business user. Thats what i created pivot table `personal_users_business_user` that have user_id,business_user_id.

I have `User`,`PersonalUser` and `BusinessUser` model.
In User model i have this relationship:

```
  public function company()
    {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PersonalUser','personal_users_business_users', 'user_id', 'business_user_id');
    }
```

Im using `attach()` method :

```
  $user->company()->attach($business_user_id);
```

It store data in pivot table. Now what i want in view is something like this:

```
  <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" name="user_company"  @if($user->company->approved == 0) ? disabled : '' @endif value="{{$user->company->company_name}}">
```

But i dont how how to access to those fields from user in pivot table. Any suggestion?

Comment: Personal user can belong to multiple business users or only one?

Comment: only one...and business user can have multiple personal users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that Business user have multiple personal users, you should use hasMany, belongsTo relationship. In your BusinessUser model you should create method:

```
public function personalUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(PersonalUser::class);
}
```

And in your PersonalUser model you should define this method:

```
public function businessUser() {
    return $this->belongsTo(BusinessUser::class);
}
```

In your migration, for personal users table add following field:

```
$table->integer('business_user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

That will make your code right. You don't need pivot table for that relationship.

Comment: if i dont have pivot table how will i approved and declined? and how will i have list of personal users that belongs to business user?

Comment: I already have business_user_id in personal users table but i will set it when business user approve that user

Comment: You can set approved column directly in personal users table. And you can get that list simply by calling `BusinessUser->findOrFail(1)->personalUsers`. This will give you all personal users related to business user with id 1

Comment: i would love to have approved column in pivot table...its much cleaner because there i will have only user that that belong to some business user because not every personal user will belong to business user,

Comment: Pivot table is for many-to-many relationship. But you can use in your case too. You can simpli access pivot table data like so: '$user->pivot->approved'

Comment: actually i will go with r first approach ... without pivot table :)

Answer (score 0):

Set relationship like this

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PersonalUser','personal_users_business_users', 'user_id', 'business_user_id')
            ->withPivot(['your_pivot_column']);
}
```

And now when you code

```
$user = User::with(['company'])->get();
```

`$user` will have the `company` relationship with the intended `pivot` column.